# Define class constant with variable

Tags: php, oop

I need to define constant with value.
I've tried to makes something like this:

```
class Foo {
const ARTICLES_KEY = $this->config->models->key->category;
}
```

But php says:  `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

I also tried to use static var, but it doesnt work.

How to make such thing properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php reads

> It is possible to define constant values on a per-class basis
>   remaining the same and unchangeable. Constants differ from normal
>   variables in that you don't use the $ symbol to declare or use them.
>
> **The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable,
>   a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.**

Comment: yeah, got it. but how make something like this? i tried private $category_key = $this->config->models->key->category; but it also dont work. why i cant define var while init?

Comment: assign `$category` in your constructor